# The Larmor's formula seem too powerful

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

According to Larmor, accelerated charges will radiate power (Watts):
[Larmor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larmor_formula)

So that means if electrons travel in circle then they will endlessly radiate power because of their constant acceleration.

Suppose we have a current going through a circular coil and connected to itself so the current runs forever. If we want the radiation generated by such an infinite coil then we have:

$$
\nu =\frac{\sqrt{\frac{c}{{{\epsilon }_0} h}} \left| x\right| }{\sqrt{6}\, \sqrt{{\pi} }\, \left| r\right| }
$$

Or:
[image: Larmor's Frequency vs Current Second]

Where:

- $a = c^2/r$ (assuming electrons travel at c)
- $q = 1\;\mathrm{C}$ (Coulomb)
- $h$ = Planck's constant (in Joules seconds)

This seems like a strong radiation for such a small current:
[EM Spectrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_spectrum#/media/File:Electromagnetic-Spectrum.svg)

How is this possible?

Comment: A steady current in coil does not radiate. Where is the graph and equation taken from?

Answer (score 3):

You're grossly overestimating the speed at which electrons travel in a wire. While the signal may travel near the speed of light, the individual charges move [much slower](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/497916/how-fast-does-an-electron-move).

Comment: Maybe but even 0.1 * c doesn't change the order of magnitude by much.

Comment: That's still orders of magnitude faster than it should be. Refer to the question I linked.

Comment: unfortunately (for your estimate) the velocity of the electron is the **drift** velocity.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drift_velocity
we are talking of about ~um/s. So your calculation are 0.000[..help yourself...]00001 * c