# Can electricity flow up down-flowing water?

Tags: electricity, electric-current, water, flow

I would imagine there are various things at play such as gravity, trepidation of the water (if any), strength of the electric current, and speed of the flowing water.

For example, if a pool of water at the base of a sink was electrified could a person washing their hands under the faucet get electrocuted?

Comment: Electric signals propagate through conductors at nearly the speed of light. What you call "flowing" water is, for all practical purposes, standing still as far as the electricity is concerned.

Comment: @SolomonSlow - indeed! Being upstream from a lightning strike is not going to help you at all.

Comment: This is a place where using the Drude model drift speed as a reasoning basis is a bad idea for all that [I defend the notion in other contexts elsewhere](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/388062/520).

Comment: @dmckee, One might ask " *what* is moving in a conductor, at near light speed, under DC conditions?  "  It certainly isn't the average drift of the electrons (~1 mm/sec according to the Drude model).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is yes, electricity will travel up moving water.  In fact it is a known problem that men urinating can get a very unpleasant shock if they hit a live wire.  Electricity travels much much faster than water.

Edit: I've just learned that Myth busters disproved this some years ago.  A urine stream breaks apart into droplets so will not conduct electricty.  But I won't test it myself.